# How to detect button press on MKMapview's annotation?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

I recently added an info button to each of my annotations with the following code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

        if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "") {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation
            return annotationView
        } else {
            let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier:"")
            annotationView.isEnabled = true
            annotationView.canShowCallout = true

            let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            return annotationView
        }
    }
```

My question is how do I go about detecting when this button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
```

And implement

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, 
   annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, 
     calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

     let anno = view.annotation as! AnnoatioClassName
     // do segue here
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. How would you go about passing specific information like a description and an image for each annotation to the next page? That is, what data structure would you use to store these and trigger the right one to pass to the next view controller.

Comment: when you create your custom annotation attach any data to it's properties as you need and from the above cast access it

Comment: I'm aware of setting a title, longitude and latitude for the annotation and that's what I do. However, I want an image and description for each annotation, what properties could I use from the annotation to set these?

Comment: this https://github.com/ShKhan9/MapCustomImage contains `MyAnnotations` class you can add an init for whatever you need